# paypal sandbox wrong access

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ND6C5P5CAVSKU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal è il metodo rapido e sicuro per pagare e farsi pagare online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I simulated the payment from the buyer, but accesses are incorrect.. Why?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "accesses are incorrect"..??  What do you mean by accesses?  Are you talking about your login credentials for the account?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below link to register a sandbox personal account.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/?mark=sandbox

then you use this personal account to simulate the payment as a buyer.